# How many pages does the memory manager switch out on a major page fault?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, kernel

In a desktop Ubuntu 12.04 setup, how many pages get swapped out during a major page fault? Just a single one?

I'm running an "experiment" where I fill up RAM until a page fault occurs, then touch the first page I allocated. This should, and does, cause a page fault. But then when I touch the *second* page I allocated, this does not cause a page fault, even though that is the most likely candidate page for being swapped out to replace the first one.

My hypothesis is that the memory manager swaps more than one sequential page at a time. What do you think?

Comment: It was an experiment I was running for an Operating Systems class.